# Is it possible to append data to a Google Spreadsheet immediately after It was created?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been running into some problems with appending data to a Google Spreadsheet Right after it was created, Using the Google Sheets API, I just wanted to know If it is possible to append data right after the spreadsheet is created?

I have researched this on google, and Stack Overflow But all the answers point to either making the spreadsheet public, or sharing the spreadsheet with the API Email provided with setup. Or is there a API using either Google Drive API or Google Sheets API making the spreadsheet automatically public?

I have been running into a error trying to do append right after it was created, The Error said `The caller does not have permission`.

Note: Creating the Spreadsheet Will Be Using the Google Sheets API

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Why the php, excel and google-apps-script tags? By the other hand [tag:google-sheets-api] is missing.